# What PHP library or tool can scale the size of an existing PDF and its contents?

Tags: php, pdf, graphics, size, scale

I have written an web application that dynamically creates PDFs that contain only 1-page that has various vector graphics in it, say for example a complex pie or bar chart.  In the back-end I have need to scale this PDF and its contents programaticaly to a few different sizes for print.

The few tools I've looked at so far for PHP seem to generate an image out of the original PDF and scale that, which doesn't work for me, I need the contents to remain vectorized and scale with the document.

Any pointers?

Comment: This sounds pretty much impossible with any PHP library. You will probably have to look outside PHP, at command-line tools and 3rd party products

Comment: Your only option seems ghostscript. But I can't find a complete options snippet which accomplishes the scaling.

Comment: I'm confused. If it's vector, why do you need to scale it? Wouldn't the PDF viewer be able to zoom in and out as the user pleases? Are you trying to solve something that's not a problem?

Comment: Sure you can scale it in any viewer and do so just before you print.  But the point is we want an automatic solution, that scales the document (and its contents) to a few different proportional sizes and submitted for print without user interaction.  Still haven't found a solution.  I've seen references to PDFLIB being able to scale a PDFs coordinate system which I think is what I want, but we can't pay for PDFLIB.

Answer (score 0):

probably the simples walkaround would be to generate different PDF files for different page sizes from your original web-application